# Casting a CAN Message to regular values

Tags: c, can-bus

I'm getting a CAN message 8 bytes length
and that's it format

[image: spreadsheet with format details]

I'm getting Lat and Long as

```
a9 00 ff 0f 32 ff cf 7f
```

Hope I get a C code that interprets the value.

The expected values, 53.3, 10.0

Comment: @P__J__ I don't want code at least, I want the math

Comment: really? `Hope I get a C code that interprets the value.`

Comment: If you have a device, you should have the data sheet for it. It probably tells you exactly what to do. Is it NMEA 2000?

Comment: @yhyrcanus I don't know about which device is it, I have the hex values as it is

Comment: GPS receivers with a CAN interface might be using their own protocol. Without the datasheet or some other description of the protocol it's using, there's no way to know how to interpret those bytes.

Comment: Are you sure that the binary data and the expected values are matching? I.e. si the binary data generated exactly for these coordinates? Also is it 53.3 North or South? Is it 10.0 West or East? Do you have any information on whether the data is transferred little-endian or big endian?

Comment: @M.Spiller he's from germany (look at the excel doc), so it's north and east. I spent around 2 hours last week playing around with it as a fixed point number (how i'd design it: longitude is out of 180, lat is 90) and got nowhere with it. I'd suggest he drives around the autobahn and record more points.

Answer (score -1):

That message you posted is hexadecimal, so it can be easily translated into values. 
Remembering that hex is a base 16 number, to convert to decimals we do for example:

cf = (12 * 16^1) + (15 * 16^0) = 12*16 + 15*1 = 207

The exponent is the position of the digit starting from the right, while the number that is multiplied by is the decimal equivalent of the hex.

More on hex [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

Comment: How is that related to my can message example ? Can you do your solution on the CAN message example and show how the expected values are calculated ?

Comment: I suspect those values are not binary integers but probably 32-bit floats.

Comment: Based on the expected result I think it's possible. But this might still be useful, as it seems that the question is more about the math behind it than actual code.